# Haskell: A function that takes a list xs and an integer n and returns all list of length n with elements from xs

Tags: list, haskell

I have tried to solve this problem before, and I've searched for a solution and could never find one.

I need a function that takes a list xs and an integer n and returns all list of length n with elements from xs. For example:

```
function [0,1] 3 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

I have tried this:

```
list _ 0 = []
list xs n = do
    y <- xs
    ps <- list xs (n-1)
    return y : ps
```

and this:

```
list _ 0 = []
list xs n = do
    y <- xs
    y : list xs (n-1)
```

None work as intended. I want to know two things:
Why doesn't these work?
How should I modify them so that they work?

Comment: Is this homework? If it is then tag it as so!

Comment: Do you deliberately avoid list comprehensions? `do` is of course fine, but IMO harder to understand for tasks like this.

Comment: I found it hard to do with list comprehension, couldn't wrap my head around it. :-)

Comment: It's only `listL' 0 _ =[[]]; listL' n xs = [y:ps | y<-xs, ps<-listL'(n-1)xs]`. — If I had to do it without list-specific syntax, I'd rather use applicatives: `listL' n xs = (:) <$> xs <*> listL'(n-1)xs`.

Comment: @Undreren This is [`replicateM` from Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) but for lists only.

Comment: @dave4420 I didn't know that one :) Only learned about monads a week ago, so sadly, these things are not that trivial. Yet. :)

Comment: @leftaroundabout As with monads, applicatives are kind of new too, but that implementation is way more intuitive than what I wrote, even to myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're very close!  Your problem is your base case, `list _ 0 = []`.

What you're saying there is that there are no lists of length 0 with elements from xs, when in fact there is one, the empty list.

Try

```
list _ 0 = [[]]
list xs n = do
  y <- xs
  ps <- list xs (n-1)
  return $ y : ps
```

Comment: Or, `list _ 0 = return []` in keeping with the monad theme!

Comment: This won't compile?
    stuff.hs:5:20:
     Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 = [a1]
     Expected type: [[a1]]
       Actual type: [a1]
     In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ps'
     In the expression: return y : ps

Comment: Don't you need `return $ y : ps`?